# Granting Namespace Permissions in Apache Pulsar

Tags: java, messaging, apache-pulsar

I've been looking into Apache Pulsar for a while for functionality and am quite happy. However, I just got into authentication/authorization and encountered a strange error with the Java admin client.

While I was able to perform all kinds of actions, like create/delete tenant, create/delete namespaces, create/delete partitioned topics, adding admin roles to tenants etc, when trying to grant namespace permissions to a role using

`org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.Namespaces.grantPermissionOnNamespace()`

I get this error:

`org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.PulsarAdminException$ServerSideErrorException: HTTP 501 Not Implemented`

I can't believe such an important feature wouldn't be implemented, so I'm guessing the error just obscures something else.

I created a new tenant (without any admin role) with a new namespace. The role I tried to add is just made up, I'm not sure it has to be registered somewhere first (but I didn't find anything to do that). I tried granting consume or produce actions separately and both at the same time, but nothing worked.

There is no super-user configured on the broker, but considering I could literally execute all other operations without it, it seems far-fetched that only a super-user could do this. Currently all calls are not authenticated. Could that be a problem? But that would raise the same question: Why could I do everything else, just not granting permissions?

So what am I missing?

We're running Pulsar version 2.5.0 and also the Java pulsar-client-admin Maven artifact version 2.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so using the the pulsar admin CLI revealed more information when trying to execute the same operation:

> Authorization is not enabled
>
> Reason: HTTP 501 Not Implemented

Obviously I missed to actually enable authorization in the broker configuration. Since I was curious where the first line came from (as I didn't get that in my implementation), I ran through the CLI source code and it turns out that the CLI prints 2 lines from the PulsarAdminException:

```
System.err.println(e.getHttpError());
System.err.println();
System.err.println("Reason: " + e.getMessage());
```

OK, seems reverse to me that getHttpError() returns "Authorization is not enabled" and getMessage() "HTTP 501 Not Implemented", but at least I now know what is happening...